# Iterating through a multi-level XML file

Tags: arrays, xml

Assume an XML file with the following structure (below). All "Family" nodes of varying depth' are under the 'root' element. (Apologies for possible incorrect terms; new at this XML stuff.)

Under the "Family" node, there are layers of "Ancestors"  or generations. So in the example below, "David" (level 1) has a father named "Samuel" (level 2), who has a father named "Fred" (level 3), etc.

There are multiple "Family" nodes. Each Family may have a variable number of layers of "Ancestors". In the example below, the "Ancestors" are 5 generations deep. Other "Family" Nodes might be 3 generations deep, or 8 generations deep. The number of generations in each "Family" node is unknown.

I need to display the Names like this:

```
David ->Samuel->Fred->John->Frank->Robert  (for a 5 generation list)
Mary->Lisa->Karen  (for a 3 generation list)
```

So I need to loop through each Family node, as 'deep' (number of 'generations') as that Family goes, and produce a list of names like above. The number of generations might be different for each family.

```
 <root>
    <Family>
        <ID>7588784011</ID>
        <Name>David</Name>
        <Ancestors>
            <Family>
                <ID>157050011</ID>
                <Name>Samuel</Name>
                <Ancestors>
                    <Family>
                        <ID>157028011</ID>
                        <Name>Fred</Name>
                        <Ancestors>
                            <Family>
                                <ID>154606011</ID>
                                <Name>John</Name>
                                <Ancestors>
                                    <Family>
                                        <ID>133141011</ID>
                                        <Name>Frank</Name>
                                        <IsCategoryRoot>1</IsCategoryRoot>
                                        <Ancestors>
                                            <Family>
                                                <ID>133140011</ID>
                                                <Name>Robert</Name>
                                            </Family>
                                        </Ancestors>
                                    </Family>
                                </Ancestors>
                            </Family>
                        </Ancestors>
                    </Family>
                </Ancestors>
            </Family>
        </Ancestors>
    </Family>
    <Family>
        // more ancestors of a varying number
    </Family>
 </root>
```

Thanks.

**Added**

I've made some progress on this, with the code as shown in My code is here https://3v4l.org/GV0UV . The code has the XML content, with the names of family members starting with a different number for each family.

I get the names of each family member output, but all names are on one line. The intent is to have each family's names displayed on a separate line.

So I need to insert a `<br>` when the family changes.

Answer (score 0):

This comes down to basic computer science. You have a recursive tree structure, and to manipulate it you will generally want to use a recursive tree-walking algorithm. This is why many people find XSLT the simplest solution for processing XML, because the recursive tree-walking pattern is built in to its processing model (xsl:apply-templates and template rules).

But you can do the same thing in any modern programming language. The basic building block is a function that does:

```
function process(element X) {
  do something with X
  for each child C of X {
     process(C)
  }
  do something more with X
}
```

The terminology of XML trees unfortunately clashes with the terminology of your family tree, because you are using child nodes in the XML to represent ancestors in your family. That's just something to watch out for so you don't get muddled.

Since your tree doesn't actually branch (no-one seems to have more than one immediate ancestor) the solution can actually be simplified; in XPath 2.0 it's simply `string-join(//Name, '->')`. But perhaps that's exploiting a property of your example which doesn't generalise to the real data.

Comment: Somewhat helpful, but doesn't seem to work with nodes that have varying 'deepness'. See the question as to the output that I want to get. The example xml that I provided is similar to the actual XML file (from the Amazon API output).

Comment: Please show your non-working code (preferably in a new question) and then we can help you to see where you went wrong.

Comment: My code is here https://3v4l.org/GV0UV . Output should show each 'family' on a separate line. (each group of families has names starting with the same number. XML is part of the code.).