# XML recursive iteration grouping

Tags: php, xml

An XML file with varying depths of 'children' in a family needs to be parsed to get all the descendents into a list.

As shown in the example code at https://3v4l.org/GV0UV , which includes the XML, the code that processes the XML is this, where `$buffer` contains the XML:

```
$xml       = new SimpleXMLIterator($buffer);
$recursive = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($xml);

foreach ($recursive as $tag => $object) {
    if ($tag !== 'Name') { 
        continue;
    }

        echo "-> " . $object ;
}
```

The output is this

```
-> 1David-> 1Samuel-> 1Fred-> 1John-> 1Frank-> 1Robert-> 2David-> 2Samuel-> 2Fred-> 2John-> 3David-> 3Samuel-> 3Fred-> 3John-> 3Frank
```

I need to separate this into families ('1David' is a person in a different family than '2David'; in real world, assume different names for each family member).

The desired output should be like this:

```
-> 1David-> 1Samuel-> 1Fred-> 1John-> 1Frank-> 1Robert
-> 2David-> 2Samuel-> 2Fred-> 2John
-> 3David-> 3Samuel-> 3Fred-> 3John-> 3Frank
```

So the `RecursiveIteratorIterator` is finding all of the 'name' values in the XML, but the output needs to be separated into 'families'.

How do I separate the extraction of the names into families?

(Note: my previous question is here [Iterating through a multi-level XML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58295290/iterating-through-a-multi-level-xml-file) ; it was suggested that I start a new question.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply check the level of the `RecursiveIteratorIterator` (using [`getDepth()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/recursiveiteratoriterator.getdepth.php)) which will tell you how far into the nesting you are.  1 means you are at the top level...

```
foreach ($recursive as $tag => $object) {
    if ($tag !== 'Name') {
        continue;
    }

    if ( $recursive->getDepth() == 1 )  {
        echo PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo "-> " . $object ;
}
```

which will echo out...

```
-> 1David-> 1Samuel-> 1Fred-> 1John-> 1Frank-> 1Robert
-> 2David-> 2Samuel-> 2Fred-> 2John
-> 3David-> 3Samuel-> 3Fred-> 3John-> 3Frank
```

Although it does have a blank line at the front, this should be easy to remove.

To turn this into something which stores the data...

```
$output = [];
$family = [];
foreach ($recursive as $tag => $object) {
    if ($tag !== 'Name') {
        continue;
    }

    if ( $recursive->getDepth() == 1 )  {
        if (!empty($family) )   {
            $output[] = $family;
            $family = [];
        }
    }
    $family[] = (string)$object;
}
if (!empty($family) )   {
    $output[] = $family;
}

print_r($output);
```

gives...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1David
            [1] => 1Samuel
            [2] => 1Fred
            [3] => 1John
            [4] => 1Frank
            [5] => 1Robert
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2David
            [1] => 2Samuel
            [2] => 2Fred
            [3] => 2John
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3David
            [1] => 3Samuel
            [2] => 3Fred
            [3] => 3John
            [4] => 3Frank
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks!  The getDepth() is what I needed for my beginning understanding of how to parse XML.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different approach for this using Xpath expressions. It is not recursive, but a lot more specific. Xpath has axis like `ancestor` and `descendant` to make the expression go in a specific direction on the node tree.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($buffer);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

// for each top level Family
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('/root/Family') as $family) {
    echo $xpath->evaluate('string(Name)', $family), "\n-------------------\n";
    // find all ancestors without ancestors themself
    foreach ($xpath->evaluate('.//Ancestors[not(.//Ancestors)]/Family', $family) as $ancestor) 
        $names = [];
        // get the Family nodes on the path upwards
        foreach ($xpath->evaluate('ancestor::Family', $ancestor) as $descendant) {
            // collect the name
            $names[] = $xpath->evaluate('string(Name)', $descendant);
        }
        echo implode(' -> ', $names), "\n";
    }
    echo "\n";   
}
```

Output:

```
1David
-------------------
1David -> 1Samuel -> 1Fred -> 1John -> 1Frank

2David
-------------------
2David -> 2Samuel -> 2Fred

3David
-------------------
3David -> 3Samuel -> 3Fred -> 3John
```